# How can I detect usb connection in Android 4.2?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, nexus-4

I used `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` and `ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED` to detect `USB` connection on `Nexus 4`, but I cannot receive any broadcast signal.

Here is my broadcast receiver code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
filter.addDataScheme("file");

debugReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(action)) {
            debugOn = true;
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equals(action)) {
            debugOn = false;
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(debugReceiver, filter);
```

Any ideas? I also searched others questions; they said if I add

`"filter.addDataScheme("file");"`

I will get the signal, but I have tried and nothing was received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` for your intent filter.

To check for connection to PC use `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and `onReceive` `intent.getInt(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED)` and see if the value is `BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB`.

Comment: I tried your method, but it still cannot get anything. Do I need to remove `filter.addDataScheme("file")`? I also try `Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`, and they can be received. But I want to detect the action that phone connecting to a PC.

Comment: Hi, Hoan. This method may not tell difference between PC connection and normal charging connection because if I connect my phone with a wall charger, the value of `intent.getInt(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED)` is still equal to `BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB`.

Comment: Well, In that case register for Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED which should show up when normal charging.

Comment: How would you check if the device is currently connected, via a single function that returns true/false? EDIT: never mind, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229024/878126