# Detect USB Connection and check if it is a PC

Tags: java, android, android-intent, usb

I want to detect wheather my android phone is connected via USB or not...for this i´m using this code:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
    return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
}
```

But is there a possibility to explicit know if i am connected to a PC?! Because the Solution i have fires the Event even i connect my phone to a printer or sth else with an USB Port...

I already tried the Solution @nios just posted, but if isCharging and usbCharge booleans are set to true, it´s not guaranted that your are connected to a PC...Even if you are connected to a Printer both booleans will bet set to true...Thats my Problem

Answer (score 7):

You can use this IntentFilter :

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                 status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// How are we charging?
int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

If `isCharging` and `usbCharge` booleans are set to true, you are connected to a PC via USB.

Hope this helps.

Found on http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Hi, thx for that informations, but i already tried this solution...but if isCharging and usbCharge booleans are set to true, it´s not guaranted that your are connected to a PC...Even if you are connected to a Printer both booleans will bet set to true...Thats my Problem...

Comment: might as well wrap the last three queries in an if checking that isCharging is true, they are unneccesary if its false obviously.

Comment: Is there also a way to differentiate between just-charging and file-transfer (via USB, connected to the PC) ?