# How to detect my android device is connected with usb or car dock through Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, usb

I am trying with Broadcast Receiver to get the my device is connected to usb or car dock but not getting the proper result. 
Please help?
Thanks in advance.
Receiver code is:

```
public class CarDockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Car Dock Receiver registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)) {
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Battery plugged AC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Battery plugged USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

receiver in Manifest file is:

```
<receiver
     android:name=".CarDockReceiver"
     android:enabled="true" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I tried to follow the the android page that explains accessory mode (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just solved a similar problem with detecting the insertion of USB devices. It turns out that - because you specified an intent filter in the manifest - Android calls onResume when something is plugged in. You might try adding this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        Log.d("onResume", "intent: " + intent.toString());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            // Do your thing ...
        }
```

Run it to see what is exactly logged and use that information to check for the correct action to check for (replace the ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED here in the above example).

Comment: This is interesting. I tried this in my main activity. It does get triggered, but always returns "launcher" as the intent, even when triggered because a usb device was connected.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether your device is connected to usb accessory, you can use this intent.

```
<activity ...>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
     android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
</activity>
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

If you are just detecting the usb connection, then just use these intents for your intent filter: UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED and UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

If you are dealing with accessories that provide power, you can also detect the connection using this intent: ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED. This intent is broadcasted when external power has been connected to the device. Here is a sample code.

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and your receiver.java source:

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("connection", "power connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide any sample example or link?

Comment: I just updated my answer. I tested ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED intent on my device and I could detect the connection with my pc. This only works for usb type that deals with power.

Comment: Yes I tried this even my curser is coming into the onReceive method but not able to get the Intent data like Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
switch (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)) {
case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC:
Toast.makeText(context, "Battery plugged AC",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB:
Toast.makeText(context, "Battery plugged USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;default:break; basically I want the Car dock related data If I connect device with car dock.

Comment: Can you post your source on your question section? I think you are doing something wrong since you are not even getting the battery-state related intent. Also, how does your car dock send a data to device?

Comment: I posted my source in question section. (car dock related data) I mean my device is connected to car dock or desk dock.

Comment: In your switch statement, you are getting the extra data from the intent to get some extra data for battery manager. However, your receiver is not getting ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED Intent. To get the strings and constans for the BatterManager class, you should add  "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" to your intent filter. Currently, your switch statement just returns -1.

Comment: Yes I got the Battery Plugged with AC or USB by using the action "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED". I guess for getting the car dock intent result need to use proper car dock instead of using data cable or usb. I checked with the following link: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

Comment: How would you check if the device is currently connected, via a single function that returns true/false? EDIT: never mind, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229024/878126